# Java: Efficient method to append N 2d arrays into a single 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, performance, multidimensional-array

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have N 2d arrays that have the exact same dimensions.  I would like to combine these into a single 2d array.  Below is an example with only 2 2d arrays

```
array1 = [[1 2]
          [3 4]
          [5 6]]

array2 = [[7 8]
          [9 1]
          [2 3]]

result = [[1 2 7 8]
          [3 4 9 1]
          [5 6 2 3]]
```

What is the most efficient way to do this?  These arrays can be quite large, on the order of 20x10000 in some cases.  The naive approach would be to use for loops but this is most assuredly inefficient, especially since I would like to do this operation fairly frequently.  I suspect that I could also use some of java's in build methods (Arrays class possibly?).  However, there are likely many different ways to do it.  With that in mind, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: you can do some index tricks to access initial arrays and avoid array copy at all

Comment: You will still need an outer loop but `System.arraycopy()`, or as you mentioned, any of the methods of the `Array` class should prove both clean and efficient.

Comment: One good way of going about this would be to convert each array to a stream, concatenate them into one big stream, and simply use Stream#toArray if you require an array as an output.

Comment: @JacobG.  Would this actually be more efficient that using System.arraycopy or Array.copyofrange with a for loop?

Comment: It depends.  If you're willing to sacrifice order, the operations could be done in parallel.  Will the arrays always be 2x3?

Comment: Order is extremely important, it must be maintained. And no.  I won't know that exact dimensions until runtime nor the size of N.  Each 2d array will have the same dimensions though.  (N tends to be small and each array will rarely have dimensions greater than 20x10000)

Comment: In that case, I think your best bet would be to concatenate streams like I had suggested before.  I can write up an example if you need one.

Comment: "Any" example would be boring. A benchmark comparing different approaches could be interesting.

Comment: You may be better off using List rather than arrays. They you could extend AbstractList to make a view of the joined lists in O(1) time without needing to copy the data at all. This won't work if you need to independently mutate both the copy and the originals.

Comment: @PaulBoddington With Lists, the boxing/unboxing will likely kill the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrays can be interpreted as matrices with rows and columns. The goal is to create a result matrix, where each row is the concatenation of the corresponding rows of all input matrices.

For each row, this can basically be broken down into two steps:

- Select the respective rows from all input arrays
- Combine these rows into a single result row

So the core of the question is: What is the most efficient way to concatenate multiple arrays into a single one? (And this, in turn, *could* be seen as a generalization of the question: What is the most efficient way to concatenate *two* arrays?)

For primitive arrays (for example, `int[]` arrays), I can think of three basic approaches for this:

- Using `System.arraycopy`

  ```
  private static int[] combineWithArraycopy(int[]... arrays)
  {
      // Assuming the same length for all arrays!
      int length = arrays[0].length;
      int result[] = new int[arrays.length * length];
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
      {
          System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, i * length, length);
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```
- Using an `IntBuffer`

  ```
  private static int[] combineWithBuffer(int[]... arrays)
  {
      // Assuming the same length for all arrays!
      int length = arrays[0].length;
      int result[] = new int[arrays.length * length];
      IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(result);
      for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
      {
          buffer.put(arrays[i]);
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```
- Using `IntStream`

  ```
  private static int[] combineWithStreams(int[] ... arrays)
  {
      return Stream.of(arrays).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
  }
  ```

Intuitively, I'd place my bets on `System.arraycopy`. It has basically no overhead, and boils down to one of the most elementary operations that a computer can perform *at all* - namely: Copy memory from here to there.

---

Side note: In your particular case, there is another possible option for optimization. Namely, to call this method for all the rows *in parallel*. But since the operation is solely memory-bound, and the memory transfer speed is largely independent of the number of CPUs, this likely has no noticable effect.

---

Here is an example that compares the three approaches.

**This is not a perfectly reliable benchmark**.

But it takes into account some microbenchmarking best practices, and gives a rough estimate of the performance that one could expect:

```
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ArraycopyStreamPerformance
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        basicTest();

        int runs = 100;
        int minNum = 2;
        int maxNum = 8;
        int minRows = 2;
        int maxRows = 20;
        int minCols = 100;
        int maxCols = 10000;
        for (int num = minNum; num <= maxNum; num *= 2)
        {
            for (int rows = minRows; rows <= maxRows; rows += 2)
            {
                for (int cols = minCols; cols <= maxCols; cols *= 10)
                {
                    runTest(num, rows, cols, runs);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void runTest(int num, int rows, int cols, int runs)
    {
        int arrays[][][] = new int[num][rows][cols];

        long before = 0;
        long after = 0;

        int blackHole = 0;

        // arraycopy
        before = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            int resultA[][] = combineRows(
                ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithArraycopy, arrays);
            blackHole += resultA[0][0];
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, 
            "%2d arrays, %3d rows, %6d cols, arraycopy         : %8.3fms\n", 
            num, rows, cols, (after - before) / 1e6);


        // arraycopy parallel
        before = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            int resultA[][] = combineRowsParallel(
                ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithArraycopy, arrays);
            blackHole += resultA[0][0];
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, 
            "%2d arrays, %3d rows, %6d cols, arraycopy parallel: %8.3fms\n", 
            num, rows, cols, (after - before) / 1e6);


        // buffer
        before = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            int resultB[][] = combineRows(
                ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithBuffer, arrays);
            blackHole += resultB[0][0];
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, 
            "%2d arrays, %3d rows, %6d cols, buffer            : %8.3fms\n", 
            num, rows, cols, (after - before) / 1e6);


        // buffer parallel
        before = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            int resultB[][] = combineRowsParallel(
                ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithBuffer, arrays);
            blackHole += resultB[0][0];
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, 
            "%2d arrays, %3d rows, %6d cols, buffer    parallel: %8.3fms\n", 
            num, rows, cols, (after - before) / 1e6);


        // streams
        before = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < runs; i++)
        {
            int resultC[][] = combineRows(
                ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithStreams, arrays);
            blackHole += resultC[0][0];
        }
        after = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.printf(Locale.ENGLISH, 
            "%2d arrays, %3d rows, %6d cols, stream            : %8.3fms (" + 
            blackHole + ")\n", num, rows, cols, (after - before) / 1e6);
    }



    private static void basicTest()
    {
        int array1[][] =
        {
            { 1, 2 },
            { 3, 4 },
            { 5, 6 } 
        };

        int array2[][] =
        {
            { 7, 8 },
            { 9, 1 },
            { 2, 3 } 
        };

        int result[][] =
        {
            { 1, 2, 7, 8 },
            { 3, 4, 9, 1 },
            { 5, 6, 2, 3 } 
        };
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(result));

        int resultA[][] = combineRows(
            ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithArraycopy, array1, array2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultA));
        int resultB[][] = combineRows(
            ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithBuffer, array1, array2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultB));
        int resultC[][] = combineRows(
            ArraycopyStreamPerformance::combineWithStreams, array1, array2);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultC));
    }




    private static int[][] selectRows(int row, int[][]... arrays)
    {
        int result[][] = new int[arrays.length][];
        for (int j = 0; j < arrays.length; j++)
        {
            result[j] = arrays[j][row];
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[][] combineRows(
        Function<int[][], int[]> mergeFunction, int[][]... arrays)
    {
        int rows = arrays[0].length;
        int result[][] = new int[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            result[i] = mergeFunction.apply(selectRows(i, arrays));
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[] combineWithArraycopy(int[]... arrays)
    {
        // Assuming the same length for all arrays!
        int length = arrays[0].length;
        int result[] = new int[arrays.length * length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
        {
            System.arraycopy(arrays[i], 0, result, i * length, length);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[] combineWithBuffer(int[]... arrays)
    {
        // Assuming the same length for all arrays!
        int length = arrays[0].length;
        int result[] = new int[arrays.length * length];
        IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.wrap(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
        {
            buffer.put(arrays[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static int[] combineWithStreams(int[] ... arrays)
    {
        return Stream.of(arrays).flatMapToInt(IntStream::of).toArray();
    }



    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE =
        createFixedTimeoutExecutorService(
            Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    public static ExecutorService createFixedTimeoutExecutorService(
        int poolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit timeUnit)
    {
        ThreadPoolExecutor e = 
            new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
                keepAliveTime, timeUnit, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        e.allowCoreThreadTimeOut(true);
        return e;
    }

    private static int[][] combineRowsParallel(
        Function<int[][], int[]> mergeFunction, int[][]... arrays)
    {
        int rows = arrays[0].length;
        int result[][] = new int[rows][];
        List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            tasks.add(Executors.callable(() ->
            {
                result[index] = mergeFunction.apply(selectRows(index, arrays));
            }));
        }
        try
        {
            EXECUTOR_SERVICE.invokeAll(tasks);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

The output on my (old, slow) PC is along the lines of this:

```
 ...
 8 arrays,  20 rows,  10000 cols, arraycopy         :  354.977ms
 8 arrays,  20 rows,  10000 cols, arraycopy parallel:  327.749ms
 8 arrays,  20 rows,  10000 cols, buffer            :  328.717ms
 8 arrays,  20 rows,  10000 cols, buffer    parallel:  312.522ms
 8 arrays,  20 rows,  10000 cols, stream            : 2044.017ms (0)
```

Showing that the parallelization brings no speedup that would be worth the effort, and in general, the `arraycopy` and `IntBuffer` based approach have roughly the same performance.

YMMV. If someone has the patience to do a JMH run for that, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Excellent answer!  Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static int[][] append(int[][]... matrices) {
    int size = matrices.length;
    int rows = matrices[0].length;
    int cols = matrices[0][0].length;
    int[][] result = new int[rows][cols * size];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < size; ++j, k += cols)
            System.arraycopy(matrices[j][i], 0, result[i], k, cols);
    return result;
}
```

And

```
int[][] a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
int[][] b = {{7, 8}, {9, 1}, {2, 3}};
int[][] result = append(a, b);
for (int[] e : result)
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(e));
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8]
[3, 4, 9, 1]
[5, 6, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, using the for loop with arrays of this kind is better than using streams or lists.

But that is just my opinion...

I'd multithread (which is an overkill for small arrays due to Thread creation overhead). Multithreading may be an overkill even with arrays for the size of 20*10000; However, if you need to do it multiple times, then you could use an executorService. But that depends on your needs...

Here's an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(100, 20, 3);
    test(7, 3, 4);
    test(3,7,4);
}

private static void test(int outerSize, int innerSize, int numberOfArrays) {
    int[][][] arrays = new int[numberOfArrays][outerSize][innerSize];
    int[][] resultArray;
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("Testing " + numberOfArrays + " arrays, " + outerSize + " by " + innerSize);
    for (int arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < numberOfArrays; arrayIndex++)
        for (int outerIndex = 0; outerIndex < outerSize; outerIndex++) {
            for (int innerIndex = 0; innerIndex < innerSize; innerIndex++) {
                arrays[arrayIndex][outerIndex][innerIndex] = counter++;
            }
        }
    // Change number of threads here;
    resultArray = new ArrayCombiner(5, arrays).combine();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(resultArray));
}

static class ArrayCombiner {
    private final int[][][] sources;
    private final int[][] resultArray;
    private final int innerSourceLength, outerSourceLength, numberOfThreads;

    public ArrayCombiner(int numberOfThreads, int[][]... sources) {
        this.sources = sources;
        this.numberOfThreads = numberOfThreads;
        resultArray = new int[outerSourceLength = sources[0].length][(innerSourceLength = sources[0][0].length)
                * sources.length];
    }

    public int[][] combine() {
        if (numberOfThreads <= 1) {
            combinePortion(0, outerSourceLength);
        } else {
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                (threads[(int) i] = new Thread(runnableToCombinePortion(i))).start();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
                try {
                    threads[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return resultArray;
    }

    private Runnable runnableToCombinePortion(int threadIndex) {
        int outerFrom = (int) ((float) threadIndex / numberOfThreads * outerSourceLength),
                outerTo = (int) ((float) (1 + threadIndex) / numberOfThreads * outerSourceLength);
        return () -> {
            combinePortion(outerFrom, outerTo);
        };
    }

    private void combinePortion(int outerFrom, int outerTo) {
        for (int outerIndex = outerFrom; outerIndex < outerTo; outerIndex++) {
            for (int sourceIndex = 0; sourceIndex < sources.length; sourceIndex++) {
                System.arraycopy(sources[sourceIndex][outerIndex], 0, resultArray[outerIndex],
                        sourceIndex * innerSourceLength, innerSourceLength);
            }
        }
    }
}
```